# Why does the use of JavaScript arguments.callee result in a RangeError

Tags: javascript

The code below throws an "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack exceeded", and I'm not sure why. I thought that this would be the series of events:

the code runs on page load

the timeout callback is set up

the call stack ends there

after 5 seconds, the function is called

the timeout callback is set up again

and the call stack ends

etc.

But the console output I get is:

```
xi=0
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

the code:

```
<script>
    var xi = 0;
    (function(){
        window.console && console.log("xi=" +xi++);
        setTimeout(function(){
            arguments.callee();
        }, 5000);
    })();
</script>
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: [`arguments.callee`](http://es5.github.io/#x10.6) is *not available* under ES5+ strict-mode. This would be a good opportunity to update the code as appropriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The innermost function (anonymous function) is calling itself. Your code is equivalent to

```
        setTimeout(function f(){
            f();
        }, 5000);
```

So this results in an endless recursion.

What you want is:

```
var xi = 0;
(function(){
    window.console && console.log("xi=" +xi++);
    var f = arguments.callee;
    setTimeout(function(){
        f();
    }, 5000);
})();
```

Comment: @Pumbaa80 - thank you. I knew I was being daft, but that was really daft! Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You're better off just using a named function.

```
var xi = 0;
(function namedFunction (){
    window.console && console.log("xi=" +xi++);
    setTimeout(function(){
      namedFunction();
    }, 5000);
})();
```

You could also create a helper function if you create intervals (that you want to run immediately) often.

```
var xi = 0;

function newInterval (duration, callback) {
    if (typeof callback !== 'function') return console.error('newInterval() requires a function');
    callback();
    return setInterval(callback, duration);
}

var intervalID = newInterval(5000, function () {
    console.log('xi=' + xi++);
});
```

### [**Here's the jsfiddle to try it.**](http://jsfiddle.net/PLT8C/1/embedded/result/)

Comment: That's right, but technically it doesn't answer the question (why?)

Comment: @Pumbaa80 The question is irrelevant because I know what he wanted to do and there is a better way to do it.

Comment: @Pumbaa80 You're wrong. Read here: "The answer can be “don’t do that”, but it should also include “try this instead”. Any answer that gets the asker going in the right direction is helpful"

Comment: "Read the question carefully. What, specifically, is the question asking for? Make sure your answer provides that – **or a viable alternative.**" I provided a viable alternative